# How to increment the value of an unsigned char *

Tags: c, arrays, openssl, sha1

I have a value stored as an unsigned char *. It holds the SHA1 hash of a string.  Since I'm using `<openssl/evp.h>` to generate the hashes, I end up with an `unsigned char*` holding the SHA1 value.

Now I want to iterate from a value until the end of the SHA1 image space. So if the value was a decimal int I would iterate with `i = <original_value>` and `i++` till I reach the max possible value of the image space.

How do I do this over an `unsigned char *` value?

Comment: What do you mean by "*sha1 key space*"?

Comment: Have you tried *i++ ?

Comment: If it really is a C++ question, you could hold the hash in an std::vector<unsigned char> instead

Comment: @Eregrith SHA1 key space = the set of values from 0 to 2^160

Comment: What does that have to do with keys?

Comment: @KABoissonneault not really C++ (that's why it has C in the title). But I guess an experienced C++ developer (unlike myself) would be able to answer.

Comment: Integer numbers are numbers. Decimal, hex, octal, whatever representation you choose. Their representation is unimportant. Their range of values is determined by their size. They are stored in bytes, each of which holds 8 bits. The number is the sum of the powers of two indicated by the bits switched on. Sign can be expressed in several ways, normally in two's complement. Pointers are unsigned integer numbers also.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you want to iterate over *all* the possible SHA1 hashes?

Comment: @EJP in Chord algorithm, I need to iterate over a key space, and in this case I'm using SHA1 (although it is not important for my question).

Comment: So you're using SHA1 hashes as keys to some other algorithm? Have you considered providing sufficient information so that your question makes sense?

Comment: *"My goal is to cover the SHA1 key space..."* - SHA is a hash, and it has *domain* (message) and *range* (hash); or *preimage* (message) and *image* (hash). There can be multiple messages that produce the same image or hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your pointer refers to 20 bytes, for the 160 bit value.  (An alternative may be text characters representing hex values for the same 160 bit meaning, but occupying more characters)

You can declare a class for the data, and implement a method to increment the low order unsigned byte, test it for zero, and if zero, increment the next higher order byte, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but also for being nice and to the point.